# More Docker containers on same port

Tags: docker

I'm studying Docker Desktop, and I have a question.
I have created two ASP.NET Core applications that are listening on the same port. I would like to have them respond by name (i.e.: `http://app1.local/` and `http://app2.local/`). Is it possible with Docker?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one process listening on a given port, so to achieve what you want, you can have a reverse proxy listening on the port and direct traffic to the applications behind, based on the host name in the request.

Some options for reverse proxies are [Nginx](https://www.nginx.com/), [Traefik](https://traefik.io/) or the [Ocelot library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/implement-api-gateways-with-ocelot) for .NET.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. With reverse proxy my apps are listening on different ports?

Comment: Yes. But they'll both be reachable through the port the reverse proxy is listening on.